# Tesla P100 GPU causes RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED when calling `cublasSgemm

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

**Problem** --> get error when use P100 gup

my PyTorch DNN model works fine until I update my Colab account into Pro. after that, the GPU that Google gave me changed from Tesla T4  To Tesla P100.
But the problem is that with the new GPU I got the below error and when I test my code on the basic version of Colab that has T4 GUP code run correctly.

**Error text**

```
35             acc = categorical_accuracy(predictions, batch.label)
     36 
---> 37             loss.backward()
     38             optimizer.step()
     39 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs)
    243                 create_graph=create_graph,
    244                 inputs=inputs)
--> 245         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
    246 
    247     def register_hook(self, hook):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
    145     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
    146         tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs,
--> 147         allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
    148 
    149 

RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED when calling `cublasSgemm( handle, opa, opb, m, n, k, &alpha, a, lda, b, ldb, &beta, c, ldc)`
```

**I used three different models and for all of them I got errors**

**Configuration**

```
!pip install  -U torch==1.8.0+cu111 torchvision==0.9.0+cu111 torchaudio==0.8.0  torchtext==0.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

somebody can explain the problem for me why changing the GPU cause this error and how can I solve this problem.
like a way to change the GPU to T4 or set some argument in pytorch code

**Update**

I change my preprocessing step and lowercase all my data after that problem fix and not happen again

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @Trilarion,
Yes I couldn't find a relevant answer for my problem, so far I've noticed that this error can happen for many reasons but the answers I've found are for different situations.